# Linux vmplayer support processes linger after virtual machine is gone

Tags: linux, vmware

After running VMWare's linux vmplayer (version 6.0.3) and then exiting from the virtual machine, these support processes are still running:

```
root      1135     1  0 Oct03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-vmblock-fuse -o subtype=vmware-vmblock,default_permissions,allow_other /var/run/vmblock-fuse
root      1270     1  0 Oct03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/vmnet-bridge ...
root      1339     1  0 Oct03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/vmnet-netifup ...
root      1356     1  0 Oct03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/vmnet-dhcpd ...
root      1361     1  0 Oct03 ?        00:00:10 /usr/bin/vmnet-natd -...
root      1377     1  0 Oct03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/vmnet-netifup ...
root      1422     1  0 Oct03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/vmnet-dhcpd ...
root      1479     1  0 Oct03 ?        00:00:10 /usr/sbin/vmware-authdlauncher
root      1560     1  0 Oct03 ?        00:00:12 /usr/bin/vmware-usbarbitrator
root     11004   795  0 08:19 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/dhclient ...
root     11016   795  0 08:19 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/dhclient ...
matt     25429     1  0 13:12 pts/1    00:00:01 /usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-unity-helper --daemon
```

1) Is there any way to configure vmplayer so that the processes will automatically end once the virtual machine is done?

2) Is there any danger to just manually killing these processes?